# how to get all ROWIDS of a chained row in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

From Query change notification receiving a row id. with the received row id when i query the table it is returning no rows.
as the table have the 400 columns row data is stored in 2 blocks which in turn have a single row have 2 row ids. so i want to find out all the rowids of a chained row.

We used the following Database change Notification to get the Created/Updated/Deleted ROWID

[DatabaseChangeNotification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm)

Comment: How are you capturing change notifications? What version are you using? It sounds like a row moved and you didn't capture the new `ROWID`

Comment: I was thinking CDC, not QCN. Still, 4-number version would be nice.

Comment: Row chaining leaves part of the row in the old position with the same rowid and filtering on that will get the entire row. It sounds more like the row has been deleted or physically moved (table move/rebuild or a partition key update with row movement enabled)

Comment: updated the question with documentation of the component we are using